# KeyNotFoundException with using HtmlEntity.DeEntitize() method

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, keynotfoundexception

I am currently working on a scraper written in C# 4.0. I use variety of tools, including the built-in WebClient and RegEx features of .NET. For a part of my scraper I am parsing a HTML document using HtmlAgilityPack. I got everything to work as I desired and went through some cleanup of the code.

I am using the `HtmlEntity.DeEntitize()` method to clean up the HTML. I made a few tests and the method seemed to work great. But when I implemented the method in my code I kept getting `KeyNotFoundException`. There are no further details so I'm pretty lost. My code looks like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string html = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(client.DownloadString(path));
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

The HTML downloaded is UTF-8 encoded. How can I get around the `KeyNotFound` exception?

Answer (score 3):

I understand that the problem is due to occurrence of non-standard characters. Say, for example, Chinese, Japanese etc.

After you find out that what characters are causing a problem, perhaps you could search for the suitable patch to htmlagilitypack [here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/list/patches?ViewAll=true&ProjectName=htmlagilitypack)

This may be of some help to you in case you want to modify the [htmlagilitypack source](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/31915) yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Four years later and I have the same problem with some encoded characters (version 1.4.9.5). In my case, there is a limited set of characters that might generate the problem, so I have just created a function to perform the replacements:

```
// to be called before HtmlEntity.DeEntitize
public static string ReplaceProblematicHtmlEntities(string str)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    //TODO: add other replacements, as needed
    return sb.Replace("&period;", ".")
        .Replace("&abreve;", "ă")
        .Replace("&acirc;", "â")
        .ToString();
}
```

In my case, the string contains both html-encoded characters and UTF-8 characters, but the problem is related to some encoded characters only.

This is not an elegant solution, but a quick fix for all those text with a limited (and known) amount of problematic encoded characters.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried these cases with `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode' and it only handled the last case of "&acirc;"

Comment: @Setsu - I did not try each character. Based on my input text (Romanian language only), I know the set of problematic characters and put them all within the function. However, one should adapt as needed. This is not a decent solution, but it enables HtmlAgillityPack to do its magic afterwards.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong but I think you mistook what I meant by that comment. `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` lives in the `System.Web` namespace and is provided by the framework, instead of HtmlAgilityPack. I was just curious to see if it handled those cases.

Comment: @Setsu - yes, sorry. You are right. I have tried `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` and works only partially.

Answer (score 3):

My HTML had a block of text like so:

`... found in sections: 233.9 & 517.3; ...`

Despite the spacing and decimal point, it was interpreting `& 517.3;` as a unicode character.

Simply HTML Encoding the raw text fixed the problem for me.

```
string raw = "sections: 233.9 & 517.3;";
// turn '&' into '&amp;', etc, before DeEntitizing
string encoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(raw);
string deEntitized = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(encoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have fixed this by updating HtmlAgilityPack to version 1.5.0